# Is there a tool to obfuscate my transactions history by funneling it through a bunch of addresses I control?

Tags: transactions, privacy, history

I occasionally gift ETH to friends and family and I'd like a bit of financial privacy after gifting them. I understand this method is not fool proof to find out the source of funds, but at least it defeats nosy individuals looking at how much ETH I have and who I'm paying by just visiting a block explorer page.

I usually funnel my ETH through another account before I send it to them. I do this manually which can get time consuming. Is there a tool that does this for me automatically?

Comment: probably not automatic but at least more efficient: google for Ethereum tumblers

Comment: those all require a 3rd party fee. i rather do it myself with a script or something that does it automatically.